# Getting Gridviews Values in Session Variable

Tags: session, gridview, master-pages, findcontrol

I am trying to store values from a gridview to session variables, using a button in Gridview, which is placed in an Content Page and further in an accordion, so first I have to find contentplaceholder which have done nicely, 2ndly I find accordion and then gridview control which also found correctly. but when I wanted to find value from Grid view to throws error.. why? because i have button on gridview which is for selecting record but i used click event of button which is also.. may be this is the problem.. Plz help

```
ContentPlaceHolder MyContentPH = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
            AjaxControlToolkit.Accordion MyAccordion = (AjaxControlToolkit.Accordion)MyContentPH.FindControl("Accordion1");
            if (MyAccordion != null)
            {
                GridView MessageGrid = (GridView)MyAccordion.FindControl("GridView1");
                Session["UserMessage"] = ((Label)MessageGrid.SelectedRow.FindControl("Label8")).Text;
                Session["Name"] = ((Label)MessageGrid.SelectedRow.FindControl("Label1")).Text;
                Session["Email"] = ((Label)MessageGrid.SelectedRow.FindControl("Label2")).Text;
                Session["MessageID"] = ((Label)MessageGrid.SelectedRow.FindControl("Label9")).Text;
            }
            Response.Redirect("AdminRep.aspx");
```

Throws this error:

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: You seem to be doing far too much work to find your Gridview on the page.  Without the markup I cannot be sure.  Is the button an asp button?

Comment: can you post the html for the accordion and it's contents